# Which fields maintain the link between Jira and Aha! integration

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm looking at integrating Aha! roadmaps with Jira and see you can sync:
Jira release with Aha! version
Jira Story with Aha! Feature
Jira Story with Aha! Requirement

What I am struggling with is finding a document or article on which fields are used to maintain the relatinship between the identities e.g. If a Jira release goes to sync with Aha! version which field is used to match the records so the corresponding Aha! version is updated?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The JIRA key (i.e. ABC-123) is stored in an integration field on the Epic/Feature/Etc in AHA.  The reverse is also true on the JIRA side so both have a link to the other.

Example API Endpoint

```
POST /api/v1/epics/{EPIC_ID}/integrations/{INTEGRATION_ID}/fields
```

Request body

```
{
   "integration_field":
  {
   "name":string"key"
   "value":string"{JIRA_ID}"
  }
}
```

https://www.aha.io/api/resources/integration_fields/create_an_integration_field_for_a_epic_by_integration_id